# Alertify Prompt - Allow user to input values and submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, alertify

Using `alertify - version 0.3.11`, I am able to fetch user input details and able to show it in prompt dialogue. But I have multiple values viz. user input, dropdown values, date selection, etc

```
var totalResources = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');

//set custom button title for Form Submit
    alertify.set({ labels: {
        ok     : "Submit Data",
        cancel : "Cancel"
    } });


    //fetch user input comment
    alertify.prompt("Please enter note/remarks for this Form :<br/>Total Resource(s): <strong>"+totalResources.length+"</strong>", function (e,value) {


if (e) {
    alertify.success("Data has been submitted");

            //encodes special characters remarks
            var sow = encodeURIComponent(value);

            $.post(SITE_URL+"somecontroller/someaction",$("#frm_submit").serialize()+ "&resource_ids="+resource_ids+"&sow="+sow, function( data ) {
            });


    }else{
            alertify.error("Your Data is not submitted");
    }
});
```

Similar to as shown in below image

[image]

How could I built a modal form using alertify where user will see pre-fethced details and can input his details and submit ?

Answer (score 2):

They have added form feature in Alertify. Have a look at [this](http://alertifyjs.com/examples.html)

From their website code is as under:-

```
<!-- the form to be viewed as dialog-->
<form id="loginForm">
    <fieldset>
        <label> Username </label>
        <input type="text" value="Mohammad"/> 

        <label> Password </label>
        <input type="password" value="password"/> 

        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

And JS code:-

```
alertify.genericDialog || alertify.dialog('genericDialog',function(){
    return {
        main:function(content){
            this.setContent(content);
        },
        setup:function(){
            return {
                focus:{
                    element:function(){
                        return this.elements.body.querySelector(this.get('selector'));
                    },
                    select:true
                },
                options:{
                    basic:true,
                    maximizable:false,
                    resizable:false,
                    padding:false
                }
            };
        },
        settings:{
            selector:undefined
        }
    };
});
//force focusing password box
alertify.genericDialog ($('#loginForm')[0]).set('selector', 'input[type="password"]');
```

Answer (score -2):

That's actually out of the scope of Alertify. It just doesn't support that kind of functionality. It was designed as a replacement for the typical browser built-in functions like `confirm()` and `alert()`.

You may want to look at other plugins. Especially since you're using jQuery it shouldn't be too difficult to find something that will work for you. A search for jQuery lightboxes or modals might turn up something that has the capabilities you're looking for.

One option might be [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/blog). The have a demo of a login form there that does something similar. I've never used Fancybox, so you're mileage may vary, but there are a lot of different options out there.